# My application is declined because of covid - true or false?

Tags: research-process, internship, research-group

I am looking for an master's internship in Berlin in biology. *(background in short: I am a student in another city's university, but because the lectures are online and I have a relative here, I moved to Berlin.)* 
I am cold-emailing professors and ask them if I could do an internship at their lab. Some don't answer, some simply decline my application with that because of corona restrictions, they can't accept students. 
Can it be possible or is it just a nice excuse? As far as I know, people can go to work in Berlin. Also, this would be an laboratory internship, so I would have to attend in person.

Comment: It is more likely that they are telling you the truth than otherwise, but only they know. Ask them. But cold emailing isn't normally very effective.

Comment: Just speculating here, but what they could mean is the following: "When working with a new student, I prefer regular face-to-face meetings, which are conducive to having a productive internship. That's currently not possible."

Comment: @lighthousekeeper this would be a laboratory internship, so it would be necessary to be there in person. (I will incorporate this in the question)

Comment: Many German universities operate their labs under strict COVID-19 related regulations now. So the hassle of training an intern on top of that is a valid concern.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's important information indeed. I think that individual institutions in Germany tend to make their own rules in the scope of whatever the federal state (in this case Berlin) allows. An individual prof might even have more restrictive policies for their lab than their institution.

Comment: @Buffy But how would I ask him? "Hey, thanks for the feedback. Is it actually true?" "No, sorry, it is not true, you just sck as a candidate". But otherwise I get what you mean.

Comment: @AN_ It might also be, for example, that the professors have increased child care duties with schools closed, and need to avoid taking on more obligations than they have to. In any case you got your answer and I recommend that you not press the matter further. It's difficult times for all, very best wishes finding an internship.

Comment: AFAIK, all universities right now restrict how many people are allowed in the lab. If an intern is allowed in the lab, that means a technician or student can't go. I cannot image anyone accepting you for a lab internship. Our technicians are working shifts now just to keep the lab operating at half capacity.

Comment: @Roland x_x I didn't know that! Thanks for telling

Comment: Some people may let you. I know of a couple of labs in my institution that are open to accepting interns, but its is much fewer than normal.

Answer (score 13):

I suspect it's true. I mean, why lie? In the past, when I've decided I don't have the time or energy for summer interns, I've just replied "Sorry, I am not taking any summer students this year". They are not under any obligations to take students, so there is no reason to lie.

Most labs currently have strict occupancy and distancing limits. Many researchers are only attending labs under restrictive timetables or on a shift-work basis. Even where there is enough space for those employed at the lab, there may not be space for additional people. Even where there is, teaching people in the lab requires close contact and that might be hard with 2m rules in place. And even if all those problems can be surmounted, an extra person in a room always increases the risk. Why increase the risk for those you are responsible for?

Add into this that many academics are far busier this year than normal, may have extra child care responsibilities, or are trying to catch up with things missed during the pandemic. For example, my postdoc was out of the lab for 6 months. Normally they would look after a summer intern, but they don't have time for that this year as they have 6 months (out of their 3 year contract) to catch up on.

Comment: Plus, in some sense there is a responsibility to keep in-person activities minimal and to what's necessary to function. Unfortunately, training summer interns isn't high on the necessity scale.